# xamarin form App crash when use apk file in mobile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have created on app in which i save user data after login

```
                Settings.userId = EmpCode.Text;

                Settings.userCompId = CompanyCode.Text;

                Settings.EmpName = EmpName.Text;
                //await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());

                Application.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = Boolean.TrueString;
```

and in app.cs i put condition to check whether its save or not based on that i switch to page.

App.cs

```
bool isLoggedIn = Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsLoggedIn") ? Convert.ToBoolean(Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"]) : false;
    //MainPage=new NavigationPage(new Login());
    if (!isLoggedIn)
    {
        //Load if Not Logged In
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
    }
    else
    {
        //Load if Logged In
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

Now in emulator its work fine, but when i archive apk file and install in my mobile at first it run fine i get login page, but when i close app and reopen again its crash and cant open again, its says Unfortunately, app.android has stopped

Comment: does it work fine when you run in release in emulator?

Comment: the issue for these problems are mostly in the manifest file

Comment: yes its work fine in emulator in release and debug mode, what can be problem in manifest file?

Comment: if your release works fine, I don't think it can be a manifest issue. have you tried running the apk from your release folder on your phone?

Comment: how to run apk from release folder?

Comment: if you ran in your emulator on release mode, an apk would have been created under your release folder inside your android project folder. This is an apk that is supposed to work on all phones. you can copy the apk into your phone and install it.

Comment: running this apk on your phone can help confirm if the issue is with your phone or the way the archive feature creates the apk

Comment: ok got it let me check

Comment: still same issue and u know i have tested on other mobile its working fine, what can be issue why its crash in my mobile can be permission issue?

Comment: you can check the permission setting for the app on your phone. also try deleting all data related to the app on the phone.

Comment: try connecting your phone directly to your computer and running it on debug

Comment: i reset my mobile yesterday, but still getting same issue :-(

Comment: if you are using vs 2017 you can also try the live debug option on your phone

Comment: i m doing now gonna debug from mobil

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your conversions

```
string isLoggedIn = Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsLoggedIn") ? "true" : "false";
if (isLoggedIn == "false")
{
    //Load if Not Logged In
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
}
else
{
    //Load if Logged In
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

I am not sure but I think you should try this code.